# UITable Cell not appearing on XIB when navigated from another XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I did an empty project on UITable Cells and it worked. Using the same code I added in to an existing project where there are multiple xib linked. When navigating from another xib to this page, the table cells did appear but the content and the required number of cells did not run.

Below is the code of my current project:

**OptionViewController.m**:

```
#import "OptionViewController.h"
#import "FishAppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "PetFishViewController.h"
#import "MarineFishViewController.h"

@interface OptionViewController ()

@end

@implementation OptionViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     self.title =@"Choose a category :)";

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)PetFish:(id)sender
{
    PetFishViewController *petFish = [[PetFishViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:petFish animated:YES];
}


// this is the sub class containing table cells

-(IBAction)MarineFish:(id)sender   
{
    MarineFishViewController *MarineFish = [[MarineFishViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:MarineFish animated:YES];
}

@end
```

**At the current sub class: marine fish**

**MarineFishController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MarineFishViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *fishList;
}

@end
```

**MarineFishController.m :**

```
#import "MarineFishViewController.h"
#import "MarineFish.h"

@implementation MarineFishViewController
{
    /*NSArray *tableData;
    NSArray *thumbnail;
     */

}

-(id) init{

    //call the superclass
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    if(self){

        fishList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        MarineFish *Item1 = [[MarineFish alloc] initWithName:@"Shark" imageName:@"Sea.jpg"];

        [fishList addObject:Item1];
    }

    return self;
}

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style{

    return [self init];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return  [fishList count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //create an instance of uitableviewcell
    //check for a reusable cell first, use if exist

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    //if there is no reusable cell of this type,create new one

    if(!cell)
    {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    }

    //set text on the cell

    MarineFish *p = [fishList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[p fishName]]];

}

@end
```

Regarding to the table. I only added one item to the fish list which is item1 and hence should only have one cell in display.

Comment: You said you brought the code in from another project? Did you add the relevant .m files to the new target?

Comment: Upload project somewhere and share a link

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?teq0bc6c37ip2nn

this is the link to the project and there are two images attached for reference. Please help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override `init` and `initWithStyle:` methods. Move your code from `init` to `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    fishList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MarineFish *Item1 = [[MarineFish alloc] initWithName:@"Shark" imageName:@"Sea.jpg"];
    [fishList addObject:Item1];
}
```

**EDIT**
Error was so oblivious...

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
       cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Must return a `UITableViewCell` object. So put `return cell;` at the end. [Here](http://pastebin.com/dS7uM8eD) is edited `MarineFishViewController.m`.

Comment: Hi,
@Mike, yup i moved all the copied the codes all over to this project

Comment: Thanks for the help but i tried moving the init to view did load but same problem still exist. Is there any other way to show the table cells content?

Comment: Thanks Sergey! that really solved my error along with changing the init in optionviewcontrollerm : 


-(IBAction)MarineFish:(id)sender   
{
MarineFishViewController *MarineFish = [[MarineFishViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:MarineFish animated:YES];
}